A white man and an African American are brothers
I have seen this movie before 2008. (English/Color)
The plot revolves around a white man who finds out that he is the brother of an African American man (they have the same mother I guess). 
Than white man travels to meet his brother who lives in a house very close to a train or a tram.
At one scene, I remember the African American asks his brother to wait in the living room while he argues with his mother (in the next room) over the topic of his presence in the house. Suddenly, they hear the sound of the train passing by, which reveals that has left the house but did not close the door. (It is indicated that he had heard them argue and did not want to be a burden on any of them).
That is all I can remember about the movie.

Sounds like A Family Thing from 1996 with Robert Duvall and James Earl Jones.

The film is a drama about a Scotch-Irish American Southerner (Duvall) named Earl Pilcher, whose late mother makes a shocking revelation in a letter that is given to him after her death. She reveals that Earl's biological mother was a Black American maid named Willa Mae, who was raped by Earl's (white) father and that she died while giving birth to Earl. His adoptive mother's dying wish is that he go to Chicago to meet his half-brother, Raymond Murdoch (Jones).

Ray lives near the Chicago L train. At some point, Ray argues with his aunt about Earl staying there, and Earl overhears it and leaves. The film was co-written by Billy Bob Thornton. Here's the trailer:



